# How do I wait for two conditions simultaneously on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads, posix

Consider a system in which a bunch of threads waits for some transactions to complete (note that more than one thread can wait for a single transaction). In order for the transactions to complete, one of the threads must run a dispatch loop. Once the transaction being waited upon by the thread currently running the dispatch loop completes, one of the other threads must take over the job.

On Windows, this is easily implemented: for each transaction, there is a manual-reset event that is set when the transaction completes. Furthermore, there is an auto-reset event that is set when the dispatch loop exits. Each thread waits simultaneously on both events. Either the transaction event is signaled first -- in which case the thread exits -- or the loop event -- in which case the thread runs the dispatch loop.

How do I implement this on Linux (or better yet, Posix)? Currently, I've replaced the events from above with `bool` variables and I have a condition variable to signal that one of them changed. However, in this arrangement, threads wake up spuriously (whenever one of the transactions complete, all of the threads wake up). Is there a way to implement this better?

Comment: Just checking: you've wrapped the `pthread_cond_wait()` in a *mutex* region, right? As for handling multiple events, what about a [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) that counts the number of expected pre-conditions you expect before waking a thread?

Comment: @chrisaycock, yes, of course, there is a mutex involved. As for the semaphore idea, note that I need the thread to wake up when *either* of the events occur, not necessarily both of them. Or did I misunderstood your suggestion?

Comment: you could fake up sleeping on the transaction by, instead of having the thread sleep on a second address, have the process finishing the transaction give a signal to the thread waiting for it, which catches the signal and exits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may not have got your scenario completely clear, but I think you could use one condition variable per transaction (but still a single mutex).

When the transaction finishes, its corresponding condition variable is signalled; when the dispatch loop exits, all the condition variables are signalled.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great idea! There will still be spurious wake-ups when the dispatch loop exits though (on Windows, only one thread is woken up when an auto-reset event is signaled). Is there a way around this? +1 in any case.

Comment: @avakar: If *any* of the other threads can take over the dispatch loop, you could just pick a random transaction that hasn't exited yet and signal that condition variable, instead of signalling them all.

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your requirement. I would create an abstraction for an event, and have a single event queue. Derived events would be enqueued, and the threads are waiting for the condition that the queue be non-empty. An enqueue would cause a signal on a condition variable.

```
struct AnEvent {
    int type_;
    union {
        //...
    };
};

struct EventQ {
    std::mutex m_;
    std::condition_variable c_;
    std::list<AnEvent> q_;

    void enq (const AnEvent &e) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m_);
        bool was_empty = q_.empty();
        q_.push_back(e);
        if (was_empty) c_.notify_one();
    };

    void deq (AnEvent &e) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m_);
        while (q_.empty()) c_.wait(m_);
        e = q_.top();
        q_.pop_front();
        if (!q_.empty()) c_.notify_one();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that in your scenario, one random thread will be woken up upon completion of a transaction. However, multiple threads might be waiting for the same transaction and, in addition, that randomly woken thread might wait for a different transaction.

Comment: I think I had an incomplete picture of your problem and an incomplete explanation of how to use the solution. If each thread has an `EventQ` to wait on, then it waits on the queue for either the transaction event or the dispatch event. Your implementation would enforce that only a single instance of the dispatch event ever exists.